# SynFusion Error : Could not load file or assembly Syncfusion.Pdf.Base, Version=16.4450.0.54

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, syncfusion

I am running 17 projects in my visual studio and SynFusion installation as follow:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAO0A.png)
these are my Syncfusion installed packages with version

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1zDN.png)

Project 1 (Start up project)
1. since its astartup project I Installed SynFusion.Licence add the following code to Global.aspx
      //Register Syncfusion license
            Syncfusion.Licensing.SyncfusionLicenseProvider.RegisterLicense("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
Project 3 I have installed following packages to Support Docx and doc to Pdf
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlRgL.png)

Project 15  I have installed following packages To Support OCR Text
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y44ht.png)
previously it was working fine olny with Project 3 to Support Docx and doc to Pdf, but now i have installed OCR after installing OCR syncfusion Doc to pdf didnt work and somehow i have mange to fix that issue now the ocr is not working. if i make ocr to work the preview doent work.

this is the error what am getting for both the issues:
Could not load file or assembly 'Syncfusion.Pdf.Base, Version=16.4450.0.54, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89'
 or one of its dependencies.
 The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

can you please someone help me in this regards.

Thank you in advance

Comment: this error will occur when there are version conflicts like one package say OCR will require Pdf.Base version `16.5` and one might require `16.4`, in this error it says, it needs version `16.4450.0.54` update your package respectively!

Comment: But ocr version is .42 then I have to downgrade the e version to .42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We suspect that the reported problem might be due to mismatched product version of Syncfusion assemblies. So, we request you to refer the same product version of Syncfusion assemblies across different projects (dependent ones) to resolve this issue.

We also have an follow up of similar query in the following forum
https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/143430/synfusion-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-syncfusion-pdf-base-version-16-4450-0-54

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Regards,

Dilli babu.